# React/Typescript monorepo without lerna

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsconfig, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have a react **monorepo** with yarn workspaces:

```
root/
├─ packages/
│  ├─ client/
│  ├─ common/
```

Now I'd like to import some `.ts` files into react.
It all works fine if the `.ts` files do not contain any types. But if I include a non-javascript character in these `.ts` files, I get the following error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:7)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../../node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

My root tsconfig.json includes refs:

```json
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.build.json", // some common declarations, like skipLibCheck, target
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@project/*": [
                "packages/*/src"
            ]
        },
        "noEmit": true
    }
}
```

Although I can compile the `common` package so that it spits out a `/dist` build, and use that, I am trying to save some time and directly import the `.ts` files, as if they were part of the current package.

Any ideas?